# Unity Build not working UriFormatException

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Please help!
I am trying to build APK for a game (Android) I have. I've tried both Build, and Build and Run, none works for me.
When I use "Build" I get these 2 problems. The first problem is that it says build succeeded while it doesn't/there isn't any build/APK. The second problem is, well, I don't know much about it. It's down below.

> **Build completed with a result of 'Succeeded' UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)**

*Although it says build completed with a result of Succeeded, it's wrong. I mean there is NO build at all. There is no APK in the folder which it builds. I've tried changing the folder, it still doesn't work.*

> **UriFormatException: URI scheme must start with a letter and must
>   consist of one of alphabet, digits, '+', '-' or '.' character**....
>   System.Uri.Parse (UriKind kind, System.String uriString)
>   System.Uri.ParseUri (UriKind kind) System.Uri..ctor (System.String
>   uriString, Boolean dontEscape) System.Uri..ctor (System.String
>   uriString) System.Xml.XmlResolver.ResolveUri (System.Uri baseUri,
>   System.String relativeUri) System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.ResolveUri
>   (System.Uri baseUri, System.String relativeUri)
>   Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.GetStreamFromUrl (System.String url,
>   System.String& absoluteUriString) Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader..ctor
>   (System.String url, System.Xml.XmlNameTable nt)
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReader..ctor (System.String url,
>   System.Xml.XmlNameTable nt) System.Xml.XmlTextReader..ctor
>   (System.String url) UnityEditor.AndroidXmlDocument..ctor
>   (System.String path)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.PrepareAPKResources.PatchStringsXml
>   () UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.PrepareAPKResources.Execute
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget
>   target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea,
>   System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String
>   companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options,
>   UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry,
>   UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess
>   (BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties&
>   outProperties) UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess
>   (BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, BuildTarget target, System.String
>   installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName,
>   Int32 width, Int32 height, BuildOptions options,
>   UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry,
>   UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:285)
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)**

However, 
when I use "Build and Run", I get below 4 errors.

> **UriFormatException: URI scheme must start with a letter and must consist of one of alphabet, digits, '+', '-' or '.' character**....
>   System.Uri.Parse (UriKind kind, System.String uriString)
>   System.Uri.ParseUri (UriKind kind) System.Uri..ctor (System.String
>   uriString, Boolean dontEscape) System.Uri..ctor (System.String
>   uriString) System.Xml.XmlResolver.ResolveUri (System.Uri baseUri,
>   System.String relativeUri) System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.ResolveUri
>   (System.Uri baseUri, System.String relativeUri)
>   Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.GetStreamFromUrl (System.String url,
>   System.String& absoluteUriString) Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader..ctor
>   (System.String url, System.Xml.XmlNameTable nt)
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReader..ctor (System.String url,
>   System.Xml.XmlNameTable nt) System.Xml.XmlTextReader..ctor
>   (System.String url) UnityEditor.AndroidXmlDocument..ctor
>   (System.String path)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.PrepareAPKResources.PatchStringsXml
>   () UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.PrepareAPKResources.Execute
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget
>   target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea,
>   System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String
>   companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options,
>   UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry,
>   UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess
>   (BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties&
>   outProperties) UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess
>   (BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, BuildTarget target, System.String
>   installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName,
>   Int32 width, Int32 height, BuildOptions options,
>   UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry,
>   UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:285)
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
>
> **Error building Player: 2 errors**
>
> **Build completed with a result of 'Failed' UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()**
>
> **UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors**... at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer
>   (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0021f] in
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:182
>   at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean
>   askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00065] in
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:89
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()

I appreciate help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking if any of your folders have a name containing a '/' character. If so, close Unity, remove the '/' from the folder's name and restart Unity.

As the error was unsuccessfully trying to say, folder names can only contain "alphabet, digits, '+', '-' or '.' characters".

Source: https://forum.unity.com/threads/uriformatexception.106996/

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had seen this source before but didn't really thoroughly followed it, thanks for mentioning again though, I noticed I had a slash ( / ) in a folder name way up the chain. The folder name didn't start with the "/", but it was in the middle. Anyway, that went away,   

But now there is another problem it's  "Unable to merge android manifests"
I've looked into a few guides, but it's not still not solved. 
In the AndroidManifests file it says minsdk 14, I installed through android studio all sdks (including 14), did anything but still not working.

Comment: That doesn't have to deal with the '/' problem. Maybe you have a plugin imported in your project, like the Facebook sdk or some other. 
Anyway, if my answer solved the problem of your question, please mark it as correct, so it may help others. 
I had the manifest problem too and simply the files were not generated correctly. I remember finding the solution on google, but if you can't find it, open a new question with more details on your configuration and errors and I'll try to help if I can, and I'm sure others will do too.